# Do particles falling through a bounded cylinder of water fall in a specific pattern?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Do micro particles (~10 micron diameter) falling under gravity through a liquid (Newtonian) in a cylinder settle in a specific density pattern upon reaching the bottom of the cylinder?
This could be due to interactions with one another and/or the cylinder wall, but I am a biologist not a physicist engineer, so my literature search has been somewhat fruitless. I thought that perhaps they would either accumulate at the edge of the cylinder, accumulate towards the centre of the cylinder or fall randomly. I have attached a schematic depicting the former two options of density patterns as viewed from the side (top row) and viewed from above (bottom row).

Cheers, Lucas.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two limiting cases to consider: if the colloidal suspension of particles is dilute or dense.

1. **Dilute**: assuming each particle is influenced negligibly by its neighbor particles, particles will not displace axially and simply fall downwards from where they were originally as a result of Stokes reversibility.
2. **Dense**: this scenario is quite complex, as the movement of the particles will generate macroscale flows that will then generate more movement, in addition to now relevant particle-particle interactions. In this scenario, I would expect particles to settle largely in the center due to the expected backflow on the cylinder boundary as a result of the original particle movement, but particle-particle interactions may change that in unpredictable ways.

For a general and accessible perspective of microscale fluid mechanics that describes this and other related phenomena, I highly recommend Brian Kirby's "[Micro- and Nanoscale Fluid Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107617200)" or Ronald Probstein's "[Physicochemical Hydrodynamics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780409900897/physicochemical-hydrodynamics)".

Comment: Great answer. thank you. In this case I think the emulsion would be considered dilute, as it is 250,000 cells/ml in media that has a similar viscosity to water. i will look up Stokes irreversibility, but in the mean time are there any published articles or books you can point me to on the subject? thanks again.

Comment: I'll add some comments regarding this in the solution; I hope they help!